# Can we use sencha market extensions in ext js 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.2

I have a very basic question. While trying to read about Ext JS Widgets I came across the [Sencha Store](https://market.sencha.com/) . I am very intrigued by the components on the store. It offers great extensions. But I am not sure if they're applicable for ExtJS.

I believe the market is for Sencha Touch extensions. Since both frameworks use more or less the same base, I wanted to know if we can use these Sencha Market extensions on ExtJS platform?

If so, is it directly reusable or do we need to take care of any clashes between the two frameworks?

Comment: Sencha is the company. Ext & Touch are products. Some products in the store are for touch, some for Ext, possibly even some from both.

Comment: Is there a list available online about the bifurcation? Which ones are for ExtJS platform?